# Flutter - getx login button does not work properly when back to login page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

When I press the login button, the login process is successful.
When I press the logout button, the logout process is successful and opens to the login page.
However, after the entry and exit process; login button is not working.
I put the print function inside the button, when I press the button, the print function works but the controller does not.

```
    final LoginController _loginController = Get.put(LoginController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    fillText();
    focusNode = FocusNode();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (focusNode.hasFocus) {
        _controller.forward();
      } else {
        _controller.reverse();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _usernameController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

and my login button onTap

```
InkWell(
                          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                          onTap: () {
                            if (_usernameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                                _passwordController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                              _loginController.fetchUser(
                                  _usernameController.text,
                                  _passwordController.text);

                              _loginController.isLoading.value
                                  ? Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.home)
                                  : const CircularProgressIndicator();
                            } else {
                              Get.snackbar(
                                  '', '',
                                  colorText: Colors.amber,
                                  snackStyle: SnackStyle.GROUNDED,
                                  snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
                                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.warning));
                            }
```

and my logut button

```
GetStorage().remove('token');
                        Get.deleteAll();
                        Get.offAllNamed(AppRoutes.login);
```

Comment: After logout, Full restart your app and try to login, if it's working then i have solution.

Comment: What you mean Full restart ? Close and open app.

Comment: It means Hot Restart.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove `Get.deleteAll();` line from logout button. because `Get.deleteAll()` delete all your Getx Controllers, then you need to create controllers again. so don't delete controllers once created.

Comment: not solved my problem.

Comment: after remove this line, need to hot restart, you do it?

Comment: yes , did hot restart after remove.